# python manage.py syncdb error on cloned project

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have an existing django project. I cloned it from repository. Then I ran `python manage.py syncdb` to initialize the MySQL database, but got:

```
...
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages /MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'appfinder.auth_user' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644749/programmingerror-1146-table-test-db-table-doesnt-exist-when-running  Previous suggested solution was to rebuild tables then import data.

Comment: Did you change the database configuration in `settings.py`？ If you are using your own mysql database, you need to create the database manually. See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup

Comment: WKPlus, python manage.py migrate gives me the same error