# Django : Table doesn't exist

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I dropped some table related to an app. and again tried the syncdb command

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

It shows error like

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'someapp.feed' doesn't exist")
```

models.py

```
class feed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
    feed_text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    upvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return feed.content
```

What I can do to get the tables for that app ?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

1. drop tables (you already did),
2. comment-out the model in model.py,
3. and ..

if django version >= 1.7:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

else

```
python manage.py schemamigration someapp --auto
python manage.py migrate someapp --fake
```

4. comment-in your model in models.py
5. go to step 3. **BUT** this time without **--fake**

Comment: The problem is, with models commented out there are errors in rest of code…

Comment: same with me.. if I comment out model, it is affecting in other code like in views..

Comment: @HarshaBiyani of course, you need to turn off the imports for short time until you comment-in the models again

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I had an issue where it wasn't adding the table to my DB in production. Spent hours trying to fix it by removing the migrations. However, just faking the migrations and re-adding the model fixed the issue. Django 1.10

Comment: Thank you. But the real question still remains... Why does this happen?

Comment: @AlexDaro there can be several reasons, but the most common one is that table gets removed manually in db level

Comment: I'm really interested in why this happened. I created a new model, and in the migrate it just didn't make it. It did that in testing and development.

Comment: This solution does not work because there is User model and if I comment it, then Django fails. It is not possible to comment the whole project and the whole Django code.

Comment: This only creates tables but with old fields and does not detect new fields.

Answer (score 23):

For those that may still be having trouble (like me), try this out:

Comment out all the URL's in the main app's `urls.py`

Then go ahead and run migrations:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

The problem was alleviated by removing the `()`'s

```
    solved_time = models.DateTimeField('solved time', default=timezone.now())
```

to

```
    solved_time = models.DateTimeField('solved time', default=timezone.now)
```

[I got this answer from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/4eiepv/getting_an_error_every_time_i_try_to_migrate/)

Answer (score 7):

What solved my problem in situation when manage.py setmigration and then migrate to the SQL database is not working properly did is following:

1. Run command : `python manage.py migrate --fake MyApp zero`
2. After that: `python manage.py migrate MyApp`

And the problem that rises with connections.py and and after running correctly the migration command is solved! At least for me.

I'm using Python (3.x), MySQL DB, Django (3.x), and I was in situation when I needed after some time of successfully creating tables in my database, that some error regarding connections.py raises. But, **above commands helped. I hope they will help all those who are having these type of problems.**

Answer (score 3):

I just ran migrations with the name of the app attached, for all the apps I had provisioned and that worked.

e.g. `python3 manage.py makemigrations my_custom_app`

After running for all of them I ran a migrate command to seal the deal.
`python3 manage.py migrate`. That was it. I'm still wondering why django behaves this way sometimes though.

Answer (score 1):

none of the above solutions worked for me, I finally solved by

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql.service

sudo apt-get purge mysql-server

sudo apt-get install mysql-server

sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
```

In my case the code that I pulled had [*managed* = False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#managed) and I wanted the tables to be maintained by Django.

But when I did makemigrations the custom tables were not being detected  or I was getting the error that the *app_name.Table_name* does not exist

I tried the following:

1. delete all the migration files inside the migrations folder (except **init**.py file) and then makemigrations then finally migrate
2. above 2 answers
3. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086444/django-1-8-migrate-is-not-creating-tables)

**PS: This solution is only feasible if backup is present or data is not important or you are just started creating the tables, as purging mysql will lead to loss of data**

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue where I was playing with same database structure in production vs development. While dropping and recreating tables will probably resolve the issue, its worth checking your database itself and see if the `model` is actually correct. For myself I created the development database incorrectly with the table names all in lowercase while in production the first letter of tables were capitalized. I used the `python manage.py inspectdb` command on production db, and compared it to the `model` and realized that in the model it was trying to insert data to table 'test' instead of 'Test' for example. Hope that helps some of you in future.

Answer (score 1):

This is linked to the migration data in the scripts inside the project not matching with the migration scripts in the database as far as I could tell.
I solved this by the following steps :

1. Delete all the migration scripts under migration folder except `__ini__`
2. Make sure that the model.py contains the same structure as the table in the database and `managed=True`
3. Remove all Django Created tables like auth_user,... etc
4. Run the following code

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

This will create the migration scripts again and will apply it to your database.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

I had another python (with a class) file which need access to DB.

For some reasons, when running 'makemigrations' this file was processed (I guess this is linked to some import chains).

In this class, I had a method containing a default arg `method(defaultModel=Model.get_default())` in the signature which was accessing to the default object in the DB (static method included in the Model class).

A the import time, this default arg was evaluated and as the table is not populated yet, it gives this error.

So I just set `None` for the default args and asks for the default model object inside the method. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue earlier when I accidentally deleted my migrations folder in an app. I was able to fix it by running manual `makemigrations` for that specific app.

Here's the fix for Windows,

`py manage.py makemigrations <your_app_name>`

`py manage.py migrate`

For other OS you need to replace `py` with `python3` or `python`

I hope this helped fix your issue!

Answer (score 0):

I have to face same issue and there are a couple of approaches, but the one I think is the most probable one.

Maybe you are loading views or queries to database but you haven´t granted enough time for Django to migrate the models to DB. That's why the "table doesn't exist".

Make sure you use this sort of initialization in you view's code:

Class RegisterForm(forms.Form):

```
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

A second approach is you clean previous migrations, delete the database and start over the migration process.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above tricks and never worked for me.
I commented on all imports and URLs that called a particular Table

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, your data will be removed. I removed the app and created the app again. I copied the app folder somewhere and delete the app folder from my project. I commented on all lines in urls.py and files similar views.py and admin.py that use this app. also app name in settings.py.

In mysql:

```
truncate django_migrations;
truncate django_admin_log;
```

Do this for all models in your app and change n.
n is app id.

```
delete from auth_permission where content_type_id=n
delete from django_content_type where app_label='appname'

python manage.py startapp your_app_name
```

Then uncomment previous lines and restore files and run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.pt migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, some of the above mentioned answers seemed not to work for me, but here's a simple 4 step solution:

```
    1) Delete the migrations files below __init__.py (don't delete __init__.py) in your specific app.
    2) python manage.py makemigrations AppName
    3) python manage.py migrate --fake AppName zero
    4) python manage.py migrate AppName
```

Hope these works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error "**Table Name Doesn't Exist**".
I was having this problem with one or two models after that I deleted the migration files that were related to my models and then again I created the same models and made migrations and migrated it and it was successfully solved. I hope it will help others too.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35539524)

Answer (score -3):

If the python manage.py migrate command still doesn't work.
Delete your app's migrations and re-run this command.

```
python manage.py migrate
```