# django migration table does not exist

Tags: python, django, migration

I have added new model to my app. I did makemigration and in my migration I can see the code to create my models like:

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Blog',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
            ('title', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
            ('body', models.TextField()),
            ('post_date', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('like', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('created_by', models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
        options={
        },
        bases=(models.Model,),
```

Now when I do `python manage.py migrate` it gives me error saying table does not exist..

Why I am getting this error. It should have been migrated right ? How to fix this issue?

Comment: can you post the whole error message?

Comment: have you added the app to installed_aps?

Comment: can you update your question with error stack trace?

Answer (score 10):

1. drop tables,
2. comment-out the model in model.py,
3. if you are using django version >= 1.7:

> python manage.py makemigrations
>
> python manage.py migrate --fake

else

> python manage.py schemamigration someapp --auto
>
> python manage.py migrate someapp --fake

4. comment-in your model in models.py
5. go to step 3. **BUT** this time without **--fake**

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27583836/4359237

Comment: I have just created a new database with no tables. All management commands say 'Table myapp.myapp_mymodel doesn't exist'.. well yeah. The problem was a Form's `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.staticFunction()` running on module load. Wrapping the static call with `lazy(...)` solved it.