# Django 1.8 migrate is not creating tables

Tags: python, django, database-migration, django-migrations

```
yekabathula-macbookair2:roster yekabathula$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, api, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying api.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
yekabathula-macbookair2:roster yekabathula$ python manage.py syncdb
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py:24: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9
  warnings.warn("The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9", RemovedInDjango19Warning)

Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, api, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

After doing python manage.py migrate, tables are not created in database from my models.py it is able to create other tables from django_session etc. Is there anything else that I need to follow here ?

Comment: Did you do `makemigrations` before doing `migrate` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. with `makemigrations`  it is able to crate migrations file. But when I do `migrate` it is not creating tables.

Comment: If you are upgrading, make sure you removed all the old south migration files from the migrations directory.

Comment: No, this is a brand new application.

Comment: the migrations folder was created ?

Comment: yes, it is created as expected. `<app>/migrations/0001_initial.py ` and in 0001_initial.py, it has all the models info.

Comment: @YSK, if this is still an issue can you post your the code of your models.py file? It may be that `Options.managed` is set to False in the Model Meta class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django migrate : doesn't create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494035/django-migrate-doesnt-create-tables)

Comment: After all options, this solves my problem! https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320071/14044451

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958708/django-1-7-no-migrations-to-apply-when-run-migrate-after-makemigrations/68882723#68882723

Answer (score 159):

I was facing a similar problem in Django 1.10 and none of the above solutions worked for me.

What eventually worked was running this command:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake myappname zero
```

This reset all migrations (to the zeroth state)

This followed by :

```
python manage.py migrate myappname
```

created the tables for me.

If you do not want to roll back to the initial(zero) state but say to the migration number 0005(the last migration that worked), you can instead do this:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake myappname 0005
```

And then proceed with the actual migrate:

```
python manage.py migrate myappname
```

More details in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#migrate)

Comment: Also you need to set models to `managed = True` if you haven't already!

Comment: @oat This saved me! Thank you so much! In my case I couldn't see the changes in the model on the DB side (MS SQL). I deleted migrations, tried altering them manually, nothing really helped... until this.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you very much. Does anyone know why this works?

Comment: @Alexander Well, my case was that I was switching between databases. So, first my app was connected with sqlite, and then switched to ms sql server. This is where the tables wouldn't create. I suppose that when you roll back to the zero migration, you are going back to the very beginning where all the tables were initially created. So there is no confusion alignment wise. Btw, it also works with Django 2.0.2

Comment: Awesome. Working in 2.0.7.

Comment: Facing the same issue now. This works for those who have migrations created but what should I do if I don't have any migrations file ?

Answer (score 33):

In my case the `__init__.py` file was missing from the APP/migrations/ folder. If you don't have one, all it needs is an empty `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into the same problem.  After lots of digging, I found the solution.
I'm using django 1.11.

If you want to start-over,

```
1)delete all the files in your migrations folder except __init__.py
2)drop database
3)create database
4)python makemigrations
5)python migrate
```

if you have `reset_db`, instead of 2nd and 3rd steps you can use `reset_db`.

```
python manage.py reset_db
```

Comment: If there are many apps, only one app is in trouble, drop database is not a good method.

Comment: Yes! i my case i only had one app and wanted to start-over.

Comment: may I also delete the 0001_initial.py file?

Answer (score 10):

I am using MySQL and get into this issue after deleting `0001_initial.py` migration file and all the custom tables evolved from DB to try to regenerate all they...

**Solved** this issue simply deleting these rows in `django_migrations` table...

[image]

After that, `$ python manage.py migrate` command regenerates all my custom tables again.

Answer (score 9):

Change managed = True (if it is set to False) in models.py

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'table_name'
```

To

```
class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'table_name'
```

Comment: You are my savior. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and just figured it out.I have multiple databases.  My local one (the one not being updated) is a MySQL database.  The others are MS SQL Server and MySQL.  I have routers to the other databases since I do not manage them and had (in Django 1.6) used the routers to indicate allow_sync() = False.  With 1.7, I changed that to allow_migrate() = False.  BUT I DID NOT ADD A ROUTER FOR MY LOCAL DATABASE.  The default appears to be allow_migrate() = False if there is not one.  As a result, the migrations just failed silently ( Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/).  I added a router for my local DB, setting allow_migrate() to return True and now my migrations actually create my tables.

Answer (score 5):

This can be very frustrating, but here is method that worked for me.
First, if you've deleted the migration file go ahead and create it again

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then compare the migration file with the SQL raw code and if it fit then apply migration

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate [app_name] 0001
python manage.py migrate
```

or you can simply pipe it from your command line or terminal

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate [app_name] 0001 | [psql] db_name username

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
COMMIT
```

**NOTE:** In my case I'm using postgresql. Though engine is similar to other database langauge, you might not get expected result.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. I did everything stated above but nothing worked. Then I realized I had not added my model name in `admin.py` file in my app.

Along with everything stated above you have to also add your model name in `admin.py` file. You have to add it like this:

```
admin.site.register(model name)
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case just one app's tables of project doesn't recreate!
and this line of code recreate them and successfully run!

```
 python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

However I couldn't find main reason caused this kind of problem!

Answer (score 3):

- Delete existing tables of the models in MySQL database.
- Delete migration folder under app folder.
- Delete all relative migration records in the table
  "django_migrations" from MySQL.
- Now you get clear model and database. Use
  `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`
  to create tables.

Hope to help you.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [how tos](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to meaningful contribute and write good answers.

Comment: "Delete existing tables". Probably very dangerous advice.

Comment: This was a helpful hint for me as I was working on a new app, but as the others have pointed out, proceed with care if your app is established with a history of data in the tables

Answer (score 3):

try this one,

run,

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

> above command will make migrations, if successful then run second command or
> check if you have typo in Installed_app and also check for AppConfig module

```
python manage.py migrate app_name
```

> if above was successful, this will create the table in db

Comment: supe weird behaviour. everything was fine, suddenly migrations not working anymore. now I had to use the app_name explicitly to makemigrations. migrate was working without it.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem for me (I am using MySQL workbench by the way):

- Run this sql: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`
- Select all the tables in your **django database** (click on the first table, then press and hold shift, then click on the last table). Then right click and choose "Drop n tables" (where n is the number of tables you just selected)
- then run `python manage.py migrate`
- Finally restore foreign key check settings by running this sql: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Note: Before taking this drastic measure, I tried what [Paulo Pessoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086444/django-1-8-migrate-is-not-creating-tables#comment53989614_33086444) said in his comment, but still I got "No migrations to apply." messages. However, this solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:** : When you apply *migrations* in django for the **first time**, django creates table of that model in database and marks somewhere in its own file(class):

```
`initial = True`
```

- When you then tries to alter the schema of that table it firstly checks 
  if `initial = True`
- if an initial class attribute isn’t found, a migration will be considered *“initial”*
- In case the `initial = True` we need to use

  ```
  python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
  ```

For an initial migration Django checks that all of those tables already exist in the database and fake-applies the migration if so. Similarly, for an initial migration that adds one or more fields Django checks that all of the respective columns already exist in the database and fake-applies the migration if so.

Fake initial migration uses both CreateModel() and AddField() methods.

---

**Solution**:

```
>> python manage.py makemigrations <AppName>
>> python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Comment: Thank you @Zahid Khan. After trying multiple solutions, only this one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to do it only for your application not from all the apps then Clear your application migrations records from 'django_migrations' table in your DB.
2. Python manage.py makemigrtions
3. python

Answer (score 1):

To avoid deleting critical databases, you may also consider silencing `properties` below the `Class Meta:` for example this model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()
    merits = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    demerits = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'weblog'
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog"

    @property
    def content_min(self):
        return truncatechars(self.content, 50)
```

You can then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` and your table will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have added your created app to you installed apps under `settings.py`.

The list should seem like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin','django.contrib.auth','django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages','django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'YourCreatedApp',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete database
2. delete `migration` folder
3. run `migrate` command
4. run `makemigrations` command
5. run `migrate` command

It will create all tables perfectly

Comment: i beleive deleting full migrations folder might not be the best idea because migrate needs an empty __init__.py file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change from sqlite3 to mysql in settings.py
2. Make sure you have correct information regarding database name and username-password
3. Delete existing migration
4. Make migration
5. And then migrate

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each app's migrations folder has a `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the connection with DB was set correctly as all the django admin tables were created on DB side. However, no models appeared in models.py

What worked for me is running in the console:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

which wrote everything into a new models.py file which then I replaced with the one I had in the app folder. Then I could alter the
**managed = False**
into
**managed = True**

here the link to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 0):

If you are a begginer like me make sure your classes extend models.Model. Then makemigrations and migrate.

```
class Cook(models.Model):
    email = models.Field()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by doing this:

- Delete all migration files and pycache so what retains is `init.py`
- Comment all implementations of that table in models, serializers, admin, urls and views
- Do `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Do `python manage.py migrate`
- Then, uncomment all implementations of that table in models, serializers, admin, urls and views
- Then, do `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Then, do `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Leman-Kirme 's answer.

I had a similar problem where the table for the model I added into `models.py` of one of my apps wouldn't get created when making and applying migrations. I tried different solutions but nothing seemed to work and I really didn't want to flush my databases. So what I did was:

1. Delete all the files in the migrations folder except for `_init_.py`
2. Delete all records in databases' `django_migrations` tables.
3. Manually make a migration file (copied from another project and changed the content so that migration would only make a model that I was having troubles with). Please, note, that it seems like it should be initial migration, i.e. `0001_initial.py`
4. Run it.
5. Voila, here comes the table!
6. If you want / need, instead of deleting previous migrations' files and records in the databases, you could backup them and restore afterwards. You gonna need to edit name of your manually-created migration from `0001_initial` to something like `<number_of_existing_migrations>_fix`

That worked for me (but I ignored step 6), I hope someone finds this useful as well!

Answer (score 0):

> Gist: => Delete entry from django_migrations and run the migrate command again.

This answer takes help from other answers, but still writing as there are different cases and my answer might help in your case.

After creating migration, I think by mistake I ran the command `python manage.py migrate campaign --fake`
 I am not sure if it did some wrong thing, so now running `python manage.py migrate campaign` was not creating table
So what solved for me is--
in mysql shell run
`select * from django_migrations;`
 Note the id of last migration which is creating problem in my case it was 62
`delete from django_migrations where id = 62`
Now I ran the migration again, and it worked this time. with command 
`python manage.py migrate campaign` 
 i.e. required table was created as a result of applying migration

Answer (score 0):

The problem I discovered working with **Postgres** is that I had not set the *schema*. I the original question is one of those gotchas that may have a number of different answers, so if the other answers are not working for you just check this.

The "problem" is that Postgres has an additional "namespace" layer which means you can specify the database but there can still be a whole set of tables, still in the same database, but in another `schema` or `namespace`.

The tables in this schema may be unreachable because the user being used to connect does not have permissions, or in fact the schema has been specified, but the tables were created in a different schema, or even you haven't specified the schema this time and are looking in the `public` schema while the tables have been created in another schema.

So the solution is to set the schema correctly, to what you intend, in every location and place that you use it. This boils down to correct database settings in all the settings files you are using, and logging in to the right schema and user when you inspect the database manually.

For example:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'OPTIONS': {'options': f'-c search_path={"foobar"}'},
    'NAME': 'foo',
    'USER': 'bar',
    'PASSWORD': 'barpass',
    'HOST': 'baz.example.com',
    'PORT': 5432,
},
}
```

The database name here is `foo`, the username is `bar` and the *schema* name is `foobar`. Adding this line to the `OPTIONS` parameter defaults the schema for all operations.

For other usage, within Postgres, you can display the current `search_path`, and alter it for the current session, or "permanently" for the database:

```
SHOW search_path;
SET search_path=foobar,public;
ALTER DATABASE foo SET search_path TO foobar;
```

If your problem was that Django was creating your tables, but just in the wrong schema or under different permissions, I hope this has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This kind-of thing was happening to me when I would try to reset my DB. Nothing else would work to get django to recognize my tables except:
`python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Answer (score 0):

In my case those solutions didn't work to me

I have to:

1. Create a new app: `py manage.py startapp new_app_name`
2. Copy all the files in my new app
3. Run: `py manage.py makemigrations`
4. Run: `py manage.py migrate`

It works to me, I hope it could be useful for you too

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally deleted the **migrations folder** from the app. So; re-creating the folder and adding the `__init__.py` file inside it has fixed the problem

Answer (score -1):

Below commands worked for me

**python manage.py makemigrations app_name**

**python manage.py migrate app_name**

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66727955/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Comment: Please stop posting duplicate answers. Thank you.

Comment: The answer is duplicated and not represent any novel solution

Answer (score -1):

I  had the same issue and lol I just forgot to change my engine to the needed one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).