# Django migrate : doesn't create tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration

After some errors, I dropped my database, deleted all my migration files (I left  **init**.py).
Now, when I run

```
python migrate.py makemigrations   // It creates migrations correctly
python migrate.py migrate          // It outputs "app.0001_initial OK"
```

But absolutely **NO** **table** (related to my app) is **created**. Only those related to django are.
And in the migration table, my application migration is marked is done but no table have been created as I said, it's very displeasing.

Here is an excerpt my migration file :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9 on 2016-02-18 21:59
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import colorful.fields
import django.core.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Client',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(db_column='idtblclients', primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('genre1', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10)),
            ('prenom1', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=45)),
            ('nom1', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=45)),
            ('genre2', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10)),
            ('prenom2', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=45)),
            ('nom2', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=45)),
            ('courriel', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=45)),
            ('langue', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1)),
            ('numtel1', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='NumTel1', max_length=20)),
            ('numtel2', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='NumTel2', max_length=20)),
            ('numcivique', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='NumCivique', max_length=15)),
            ('rue', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='Rue', max_length=45)),
            ('ville', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='Ville', max_length=45)),
            ('codepostal', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='CodePostal', max_length=45)),
            ('timestamp', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, db_column='Timestamp', null=True)),
            ('zone', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='Zone', max_length=45)),
        ],
        options={
            'db_table': 'tblclients',
            'managed': False,
        },
    ),
....
```

Do you have an idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you added the app in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes sure. When i run migrate, django tells me "app.0001_initial OK" which should mean the migration have been done (while they haven't been done as i said)

Comment: And i forgot to tell that the migration ignores all the migrations in my app migration file (the one I have copied) but the last one which is a table that has foreign keys with the first others. So mysql outputs an error.

Comment: try `python manage.py makemigrations <appname_thats_missing_tables>` and `python manage.py migrate <appname_thats_missing_tables>`

Comment: Ah you're right. How didn't I see that ! Thank you.

Comment: @rwx you are right. My problems solved, Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From Django docs, [`Options.managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#managed): "If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be performed for this model."

And I see you have

```
   options={
        'db_table': 'tblclients',
        'managed': False,
    },
```

Try setting `managed=True` in the model.

Answer (score 101):

```
python manage.py migrate --fake APPNAME zero
```

This will make your migration to fake.
Now you can run the migrate script

```
python manage.py migrate APPNAME
```

Tables will be created
and you solved your problem.. Cheers!!!

Comment: Definitely works for Django 2.1.5, also if you deleted your migrations folder intentionally or by mistake

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations <APPNAME> followed by python manage.py migrate is the steps worked for me

Comment: This is work for me. If some table already exists in DB, drop the all table first and run the second cmd.

Comment: This was great. If you need your database to be reset, this works fantastically.

Comment: Wow, what just happened? It somehow worked! What do the above lines do? how it work? Anyone?

Comment: Six years later still works as a charm. I think this occurs when you try to push multiple projects on the same database. I have two projects under the same database and both has app name `core`. I was having the same problem and this trick resolved my issue.

Answer (score 22):

In my case, what created the tables was this:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

I am using Django 1.9.6.

Comment: This solved the problem for me after I dropped my database and deleted all migrations

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed, followed by a fake-initial

Comment: I deleted all migrations - all of them. Then this worked, i.e. table was created. But it created no migrations. How is this possible?

Answer (score 19):

I had manually deleted one of the tables and the trick that worked for me was to execute the following steps:

1. Removed the migrations folder.
2. deleted the migrations from db:
   DELETE from django_migrations WHERE app='<app_name>';
3. python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb' before
4. python manage.py makemigrations '<app_name>'
5. python manage.py migrate --fake

Note: earlier I was not executing the #3 step and the table was not getting created.
my django version: v3.0.5

Comment: it's 2021 and django3, and this DELETE from django_migrations WHERE app='alerts_db'; command helped me.

Comment: Amazing! It's the right way to solve the problem! Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Django 3.2.7 - facing the issue of table not being created in the new schema I made in the same postgres database, but this solution is not working for me :( any help?

Answer (score 10):

I face same issue:

```
python manage.py migrate poll
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: poll
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Follow these steps to create tables for your app.

> Go to your app folder
>
> 1.delete migration folder.
>
> 2.python manage.py makemigrations.
>
> 3 Rename 0001_initial.py file to 0001_initial_manual.py.
>
> 4 python manage.py migrate APPNAME.

After this my tables created smoothly.

```
python manage.py migrate poll
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: poll
Running migrations:
  Applying poll.0002_initial... OK
```

Comment: before step 4, i need to drop all created tables `<app_name>_<model_name>` and constraints that were generated by Django.

Answer (score 5):

This worked in **Django v.3** :

1. Delete the rows related to your application from database:

   ```
   DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='<app_name>';
   ```
2. Delete your app's migration folder
3. Finally

   ```
   ./manage.py makemigrations <app_name>

   ./manage.py migrate <app_name>
   ```
4. Done. Table created.

Comment: It worked for django 4.1.7 version also. Thank you smrachi saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you are using multiple databases in your project. If multiple databases configured, check the default database is the one you are looking for.

If default and your expected database are different, run below command pointing to your db configuration.

python manage.py migrate $app_name --database $dbname_from_setting

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends if you already have a history of migrations in your app folder. In my case I didn't...I think I deleted original migration scripts.

## So following the Django docs, I did the following:

1. Comment out new updates in models.py
2. Follow section [Adding migrations to apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps)...
3. Create migrations for what is already existing:

   > python manage.py makemigrations yourapp
4. Do fake applying of these migrations (below singles that the tables already exist and not to try to recreate):

   > python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
5. Uncomment changes in model.py
6. Follow steps in section [Workflow](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#workflow) ...

   > python manage.py makemigrations yourapp
   >
   > python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1):

**First try this;**

Check your migration files for the app, if you have the *create model* portion  in your migrations file, remove it and redo migrations. I.e remove this;
   migrations.CreateModel(
        name='YourModelName',
             .......
                .....)

```
(venv)root@debian:~/Desktop/project$ python manage.py makemigrations appName
(venv)root@debian:~/Desktop/project$ python manage.py migrate appName
```

**Else; navigate to your database and delete all migrations for that app,
you may have to drop the related tables too.**

```
postgres=# \c db_yourdb
db_yourdb=# delete from django_migrations where app='appName';
```

then go to your code and;

```
(venv)root@debian:~/Desktop/project$ python manage.py makemigrations appName
(venv)root@debian:~/Desktop/project$ python manage.py migrate appName
```

**To do fresh migrations entirely, first do the necessary deletions for migrations and droping the tables if need be then;**

```
(venv)root@debian:~/Desktop/project$ find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
(venv)root@debian:~/Desktop/project$ find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

finally do;

```
(venv)root@debian:~/Desktop/project$ python manage.py makemigrations
(venv)root@debian:~/Desktop/project$ python manage.py migrate
```

[Read more here on how to reset migrations](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got @JulienD's answer to work:

1. I added metadata to my model def in models.py:

`class thing(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
            class Meta:
                app_label = 'things'
                managed = True`

2. Execute:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

3. Execute:

`python manage.py migrate`

After that `python manage.py showmigrations` shows the migrations and the admin site started working.

Answer (score 0):

Delete folder migrations and re-run. It works for me

Comment: You should NOT delete the migrations folder, but you can delete its content, but it's VERY important to keep the __init__.py in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had also that problem, all I had to do to solve it was to(I was using phpymyadmin):

**1. Go into phpmyadmin panel**

**Pick the database I connected to, and empty the table named django_migrations**

**Then, I did the usual: python manage.py makemigrations app_name**

**Lastly: python manage.py migrate app_name**

And voi'le, done and ready ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add your app name in `settings.py` as per the following:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue and I identified the problem was that my app, (which was also added in settings), started with an uppercase letter.
It is interesting that no errors were ever thrown to warn about this, but I kept seeings errors that certain tables related to the app do not exist.

So, make sure your app name starts with a small letter, and `python manage.py makemigrations <appName>` and `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too.

py manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, token_blacklist
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

After checking lots of solutions finally, I found that I've used the same environment for many projects. I was running manage.py of another project. The case might be the same as mine. If the case is not as similar to mine then all the solutions of the above works.