# Django : migration success but not creating new table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've been using django migration to handle database. recently, I split session into two, one is for reading and the other one is for writing. After done this, I made new migration file that adding new table and run it. It was successful,

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: food
Running migrations:
Applying food.0107_auto_20171116_0849... OK
```

However, when I checked mysql database using shell, there was no new table. I deleted django migrations history and attempted few times more but the result was same. It says migration applied but there was no new table. This is my migration file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.2 on 2017-11-16 08:49
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import uuid


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('bubi', '0106_auto_20171110_1452'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
           name='FoodHistory',
              fields=[
                  ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                  ('date', models.DateField(verbose_name='updated date')),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name': 'food updated date',
            'verbose_name_plural': 'food updated date',
        },
    ),
]
```

I wonder if splited session may affects to do migrations. thanks!

EDIT

I added my local_settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'food',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'USER': 'apple',
    'PASSWORD': 'apple'
},
'read': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'food',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'USER': 'apple',
    'PASSWORD': 'apple'
},
'write': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'food',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'USER': 'apple',
    'PASSWORD': 'apple'
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database? Do you see a file called `db.sqlite3` in your project directory?

Comment: @chris I added my local_settings.py, I dont use db.sqlite3, I use mysql.

Comment: I know you're _trying to_ use MySQL. I'm wondering if it's really working that way. What does `python manage.py sqlmigrate food 0107` give?

Comment: @chris it says ```Running migrations:
  Applying bubi.0107_auto_20171116_0849... OK
``` but there is no table

Comment: That's not the output I'm asking about. That's for `migrate`; I'm asking about _`sqlmigrate`_. It should output some SQL code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use multiple DBs in Django, When migrating, you need to check the Database Router that you coded.

Check for "allow_migrate" method in your database router class.

This is official Django documentation about this issue.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate

Comment: finally, problem solved. I added ```allow_migrate``` and make it ```return food``` and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

You should set database name to migrate others database:

```
./manage.py migrate --database=write
```

Comment: This solved my problem.  I created a new app called 'ABC' with separate database settings also named 'ABC'.  When I ran "manage.py migrate ABC" it applied the migrations from *APP* ABC to the default database, correctly adding no new tables there.  But I needed to apply migrations to the *DATABASE* ABC.  Instead running "manage.py migrate --database=ABC" applied migrations to the new database, first creating the new django_migrations table.  Note: it "applied" all of my apps' migrations to ABC DB, though only the ABC app migrations had effect, due to the allow_migrate database router settings.