# How to erase table data in Django?

Tags: python, django

I wrote a simple script for populating the table created with Django models. I did make mistakes during the development process and have corrupted data in my table (it is accessible but has wrong images, names, urls). I want to erase this data and start the populating over, but it looks like the table stores previous primary keys (so the new objects do not start from `pk=1`) if I just use `Model.objects.all().delete()`.

How can I erase all the previous data without `DROP TABLE`? If `DROP` is the most convenient way, is this [Django : Table doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583744/django-table-doesnt-exist/27583836#27583836) solution for restoring is the only one?

The desired functionality is erasing data before every script run, automatically. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using SQLite?

Comment: What do you mean by "before every script run"?

Comment: @doru I have different DB management systems on different machines (develop using both of them: home and work), sqlite and mysql. Isn't django orm database-agnostic in this case?

Comment: @Sayse 
1. Erase previous data with Django ORM, the table is absolutely new and clean.
2. Start populating.

Everything from the same script.

Comment: Do you mean you have a script you run? you can just add flush to the beginning of that

Comment: @Georgy Yes, it is. But if you only need to drop a SQLite db, you only have to delete the db file inside your proejct and then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again to have a new database.

Comment: @Sayse very close to it. I'll google how to add it into script, thank you. Are there any ways to use flush just for the set of tables, not database?

Comment: Not really, you can specify what database you want to flush but you can't specify tables for good reason, it stops you from invalidating database entries

Comment: @Sayse alright then. Would you please add this information (the last comment about tables) to your answer, just to make it complete (I haven't enough rating to add my comments, sorry). I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Georgy - Done, enjoy!

Comment: @doru Thank you, this is a way to drop the db with fewer iterations of `migrate`, though the using of `flush` looks a bit more convenient. Your solution helps me to understand the project structure anyway. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`flush`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#flush)

> Removes all data from the database and re-executes any post-synchronization handlers. The table of which migrations have been applied is not cleared.

Called via `manage.py flush`

> Are there any ways to use flush just for the set of tables, not database?

No, not really. Flush has an option to specify what database you're flushing (`-database`) but you can't specify certain tables since that has the possibility of breaking relationships between tables which would invalidate data.

If you really need to do this, you could of course make your own command that will just go through the tables and delete the objects but this of course won't do the `post-synchronization` steps that flush does

Comment: A little hack, if you use this command a lot then you can type in `python manage.py flush --noinput` - no need to type in `yes` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to drop only the tables of a given django app and not the whole database: you can use `sqlclear` and pipe it to `dbshell` management command.

```
python manage.py sqlclear app_name | python manage.py dbshell
```

The command can be applied only if the app has no migrations. See [here](http://django.zone/blog/posts/django-data-management-commands/) more info.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed a way to clear particular tables before using loaddata to backport data to test environments. This works for a particular table:

```
echo "delete from my_table" | python manage.py dbshell
```