# MySQL Test DB Failing

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I set up a Django 2 app (and Python 3.6) with a remote MySQL DB (using `mysqlclient`), with proper permissions.

When I run my unit test, I get the following error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, “Table ‘test_<db>.<db>’ doesn’t exist”)`.

When I manually open the website at `localhost`, everything works fine.

Technically I could create a local dev DB for testing, but I would prefer that the test DB is created automatically.

EDIT

It seems like the issue was related to my tables not being managed by Django, [see here](https://dev.to/patrnk/testing-against-unmanaged-models-in-django).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me:

Changing my tables to `managed = True`.

Deleting migration files (except `__init__.py`).

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

And now my unit tests are running.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate.

[Django : Table doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583744/django-table-doesnt-exist)

If the table is missing, make sure you've got the right migration file (`python manage.py makemigrations`) and that you've applied it (`python manage.py migrate`).

Comment: I haven't dropped any migrations and my migrations were done properly. When I manually open my website, everything runs perfectly.

Comment: Is the table that you're trying to access in the test defined in the migration files?  The test DB is not (necessarily) the same one you use when running the unit tests.

Comment: The table is defined in the migration file. Doesn't Django create a test DB automatically using the DB Engine config?