# pg_restore not restoring a certain table?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, psql, pg-restore

In a Django project, I have a model `Question` in the `lucy_web` app, but the corresponding `lucy_web_question` table does not exist, as seen from a `\dt` command in the database shell:

```
(lucy-web-CVxkrCFK) bash-3.2$ python manage.py dbshell
psql (10.4)
Type "help" for help.

lucy=> \dt
                    List of relations
 Schema |             Name             | Type  |  Owner  
--------+------------------------------+-------+---------
 public | auditlog_logentry            | table | lucyapp
 public | auth_group                   | table | lucyapp
 public | auth_group_permissions       | table | lucyapp
 public | auth_permission              | table | lucyapp
 public | auth_user                    | table | lucyapp
 public | auth_user_groups             | table | lucyapp
 public | auth_user_user_permissions   | table | lucyapp
 public | defender_accessattempt       | table | lucyapp
 public | django_admin_log             | table | lucyapp
 public | django_content_type          | table | lucyapp
 public | django_migrations            | table | lucyapp
 public | django_session               | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_checkin             | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_checkintype         | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_company             | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_expert              | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_expertsessiontype   | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_family              | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_lucyguide           | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_notification        | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_package             | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_packagesessiontype  | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_preactivationfamily | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_profile             | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_questionanswer      | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_questioncategory    | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_session             | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_sessioncategory     | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_sessiontype         | table | lucyapp
 public | lucy_web_userapn             | table | lucyapp
 public | oauth2_provider_accesstoken  | table | lucyapp
 public | oauth2_provider_application  | table | lucyapp
 public | oauth2_provider_grant        | table | lucyapp
 public | oauth2_provider_refreshtoken | table | lucyapp
 public | otp_static_staticdevice      | table | lucyapp
 public | otp_static_statictoken       | table | lucyapp
 public | otp_totp_totpdevice          | table | lucyapp
 public | two_factor_phonedevice       | table | lucyapp
(38 rows)
```

We also have a staging environment, deployed on Aptible, which does appear to have these tables. Using the [Aptible CLI to create a database tunnel](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/cli/db-tunnel.html), if I `psql <connection_url>` and `dt` I do see the `lucy_web_question` table:

```
db=# \dt
                    List of relations
 Schema |             Name             | Type  |  Owner  
--------+------------------------------+-------+---------
 public | auditlog_logentry            | table | aptible
 public | auth_group                   | table | aptible
 public | auth_group_permissions       | table | aptible
 public | auth_permission              | table | aptible
 public | auth_user                    | table | aptible
 public | auth_user_groups             | table | aptible
 public | auth_user_user_permissions   | table | aptible
 public | defender_accessattempt       | table | aptible
 public | django_admin_log             | table | aptible
 public | django_content_type          | table | aptible
 public | django_migrations            | table | aptible
 public | django_session               | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_checkin             | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_checkintype         | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_company             | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_expert              | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_expertsessiontype   | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_family              | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_lucyguide           | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_notification        | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_package             | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_packagesessiontype  | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_preactivationfamily | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_profile             | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_question            | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_questionanswer      | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_questioncategory    | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_questionprompt      | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_session             | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_sessioncategory     | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_sessiontype         | table | aptible
 public | lucy_web_userapn             | table | aptible
 public | oauth2_provider_accesstoken  | table | aptible
 public | oauth2_provider_application  | table | aptible
 public | oauth2_provider_grant        | table | aptible
 public | oauth2_provider_refreshtoken | table | aptible
 public | otp_static_staticdevice      | table | aptible
 public | otp_static_statictoken       | table | aptible
 public | otp_totp_totpdevice          | table | aptible
 public | two_factor_phonedevice       | table | aptible
(40 rows)
```

Because the data on these test environments is not important, I'd like to `pg_dump` the Aptible database and `pg_restore` it on my local machine.

My local `DATABASE_URL` is `postgres://lucyapp:<my_password>@localhost/lucy`, so firstly, I did a `pg_dump` with `--format=custom` and specifying a `--file` as follows:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy2 kurtpeek$ touch staging_db_12_July.dump
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy2 kurtpeek$ pg_dump postgresql://aptible:<some_aptible_hash>@localhost.aptible.in:62288/db --format=custom --file=staging_db_12_July.dump
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy2 kurtpeek$ ls -lhtr | tail -1
-rw-r--r--   1 kurtpeek  staff   1.5M Jul 12 18:09 staging_db_12_July.dump
```

This results in a 1.5Mb `.dump` file, which I tried to restore from using `pg_restore` with the `--no-owner` option and `--role=lucyapp` (in order change the owner from `aptible` to `lucyapp`). However, this gives rise to a large number of 'already exists' errors, of which one is shown below:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy2 kurtpeek$ pg_restore staging_db_12_July.dump --dbname=lucy --no-owner --role=lucyapp
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3522; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION plpgsql 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
    Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2; 3079 16392 EXTENSION hstore 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "hstore"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
    Command was: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore WITH SCHEMA public;



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3523; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION hstore 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  extension "hstore" does not exist
    Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION hstore IS 'data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs';



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 197; 1259 16515 TABLE auditlog_logentry aptible
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "auditlog_logentry" already exists
    Command was: CREATE TABLE public.auditlog_logentry (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    object_pk character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    object_id bigint,
    object_repr text NOT NULL,
    action smallint NOT NULL,
    changes text NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    actor_id integer,
    content_type_id integer NOT NULL,
    remote_addr inet,
    additional_data jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT auditlog_logentry_action_check CHECK ((action >= 0))
);



WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 294
```

The problem is that if I `\dt` again in the `python manage.py dbshell`, I still don't see the `lucy_web_question` table.

I've come across this solution, [Django : Table doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583744/django-table-doesnt-exist), for my situation, but in my case the `Question` model is imported and used as a foreign key in so many places that I thought it would be easier just to restore a database. Why is it not restoring the `lucy_web_question` table, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was that the `lucyapp` user did not have sufficient privileges to create the table. I basically had to ensure that the `\dn+` command produced this result:

```
lucy=# \dn+
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | =UC/postgres        +| 
        |          | lucyapp=UC/postgres  | 
(1 row)
```

where `lucyapp` has both `USAGE` (`U`) and `CREATE` (`C`) privileges. Following https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html, this can be achieved with the commands

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO lucyapp;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO lucyapp;
```

I also made `lucyapp` a `superuser` prior to running these commands, although that is not recommended for production.