# Table doesn't exist in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to send data from a form to a database using this model, but i keep getting this error:

```
("Table 'trades.main_SomeModel' doesn't exist")
```

Here is my model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
     data = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     def save(self):
         super(SomeModel, self).save(using='dataset')
```

And here is my form:

```
 class DataForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Trade
            fields = ("data",)

        def save(self, commit=True):
            send = super(DataForm, self).save(commit=False)
            if commit:
                send.save()
            return send
```

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583744/django-table-doesnt-exist) but it's not working: when i got to step 3, in fact, i got the error `table "main_SomeModel" already exists`

**Note: i'm using two DBs. There is a default one and a second one. The data from this model should be sent to the second DB.**

What am i doing wrong? Should i migrate again?

Comment: Did you change anything (field-wise) on your model after migrating? If so, you indeed need to migrate again.

Comment: The thing is that i don't see any table on my DB @Alasdair

Comment: I'm using two DB, there is a default one and a second one. On this model, data should be saved on the second DB, which is declared on my settings.py file

Comment: Edited right now

Comment: I think this `send = super(SomeModel, self).save(commit=False)` is the issue which should be `send = super(DataForm, self).save(commit=False)` within DataForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the migrations for both of your databases but you have run it for one database.

```
python manage.py migrate --database dataset
```

Here `dataset` is the name of the database other than your default database.

Comment: if this is indeed your problem consider using a django database router