# Getting error after changed sqlite to mysql, table doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, django, database, sqlite

i've finished developing a django project and wanted to change sqlite3 to MySql for a better database option. I tried in an empty project to change database, it worked like a charm. But now i changed db of my project and when i try to do `python manage.py makemigrations` it returns;

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'tvekstra-django-tracker.tvchannels_channels' doesn't exist")
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have code that is trying to query the database before `makemigrations` runs. [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583744/django-table-doesnt-exist). To help with your specific problem, you need to show the full traceback which will show where the query is occuring, and your `views.py`.

Comment: Turns out in views.py i've been listing channels while there are no tables, i deleted it and migrated it worked fine. Thanks for the views.py tip!

Comment: Comment out all the places which make a query(`model.objects.all()` or `model.objects.create()` or `model.objects.something`).